# Problems with tables with CSS, HTML and domPDF

Tags: html, css, dompdf

I would like to leave my HTML code this way:
[image: html code]

However my code is not working perfectly, here is my code:

```
<style>
        body{
            font-family: Verdana;
        }

        #titulo{
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background-color: #5481eb;
            font-size: 14;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            border:2px solid #000;
        
        }

        .tabela-up-left{
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #707070;
            border:2px solid #000;
            
        }

        .tabela-up-right{
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color: #c4c0c0;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 10px;
            border:2px solid #000;
            width:100%;
        }

        .tabela-down{
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #707070;
            border: 2px solid #000;
            width: 45%;
        }

        .tabela-description{
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 2px solid #000;
            width: 45%;
        }

    </style>
<div id = "titulo">
        <h1>LISTAGEM DE PENDÊNCIAS</h1>
    </div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class = "tabela-up-left">PROTOCOLO:</td>
                <td class = "tabela-up-right">123</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class = "tabela-up-left">CÓDIGO DO LOTE:</td>
                <td class = "tabela-up-right">7773</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class = "tabela-down">VÍNCULO</td>
            <td class = "tabela-down">PÊNDENCIA</td>
            <td class = "tabela-down">STATUS</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class = "tabela-description">Dados gerais</td>
            <td class = "tabela-description">Instrumento de Titulação</td>
            <td class = "tabela-description">Nenhum</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The results of my code is:

[image: result html code]
I have some problems to organize the css in the html, that is why my code is not work well. I do not know for example to organize the rows of the table, mainly the spaces in "PROTOCOLO" and "2/2021".
I am using the library dompdf. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below,

```css
 body{
      font-family: Verdana;
  }

  #titulo{
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background-color: #5481eb;
      font-size: 14;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      border:1px solid rgb(114, 110, 110);
  
  }

  .tabela-up-left{
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #707070;
      border:1px solid rgb(40 38 38);
      padding: 6px;
      
  }

  .tabela-up-right{
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-weight: bold;
      background-color: #c4c0c0;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 10px;
      border:1px solid rgb(114, 110, 110);
      width:100%;
      padding: 6px;
  }

  .tabela-down{
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #707070;
      border: 1px solid rgb(40 38 38);
      width: 45%;
      padding: 6px;
  }

  .tabela-description{
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid rgb(114, 110, 110);
      width: 45%;
      padding: 6px;
  }
```

```html
<div id = "titulo">
  <h1>LISTAGEM DE PENDÊNCIAS</h1>
</div>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;width:100%;">
  
      <tr>
          <td class = "tabela-up-left">PROTOCOLO:</td>
          <td class = "tabela-up-right" colspan="2">123</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class = "tabela-up-left">CÓDIGO DO LOTE:</td>
          <td class = "tabela-up-right" colspan="2">7773</td>
      </tr>
 

  <tr>
      <td class = "tabela-down">VÍNCULO</td>
      <td class = "tabela-down">PÊNDENCIA</td>
      <td class = "tabela-down">STATUS</td>
  </tr>
 
  <tr>
      <td class = "tabela-description">Dados gerais</td>
      <td class = "tabela-description">Instrumento de Titulação</td>
      <td class = "tabela-description">Nenhum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class = "tabela-description">Dados gerais</td>
    <td class = "tabela-description">Instrumento de Titulação</td>
    <td class = "tabela-description">Nenhum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class = "tabela-description">Dados gerais</td>
  <td class = "tabela-description">Instrumento de Titulação</td>
  <td class = "tabela-description">Nenhum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class = "tabela-up-left">PROTOCOLO:</td>
  <td class = "tabela-up-right" colspan="2">123</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class = "tabela-up-left">CÓDIGO DO LOTE:</td>
  <td class = "tabela-up-right" colspan="2">7773</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td class = "tabela-down">VÍNCULO</td>
<td class = "tabela-down">PÊNDENCIA</td>
<td class = "tabela-down">STATUS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class = "tabela-description">Dados gerais</td>
  <td class = "tabela-description">Instrumento de Titulação</td>
  <td class = "tabela-description">Nenhum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class = "tabela-description">Dados gerais</td>
<td class = "tabela-description">Instrumento de Titulação</td>
<td class = "tabela-description">Nenhum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class = "tabela-description">Dados gerais</td>
<td class = "tabela-description">Instrumento de Titulação</td>
<td class = "tabela-description">Nenhum</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

please comment if query, and this also working but i suggest use only one table if you want short code.

Comment: Thanks bro, it is works. Man, do you know how to occupy all the page of the PDF with this code? How to this in the dompdf?